# Trying to append the sum of an existing dataframe into a new excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

So I have been trying to append the `df.sum()` of an existing dataframe into a new dataframe for a new `excel.Consider` the below example:

```
A   B     C     
10  10   10
10  10   10
10  10   10
```

I want this to be appended to a new excel as:

```
A   B   C
30  30  30
```

Following is the code where I am merging the files in a particular location

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

for f in glob.glob("D:\\data_integration\\*.csv"):
    print(f)
    df = pd.read_csv(f ,encoding='iso-8859-1')
    
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
    print(all_data)
    
    ##appended_df = pd.concat(all_data)
    y = all_data.to_csv("D:\\merged2.csv",index=False)
```

I need help with the summing part.

Comment: `df.sum().to_frame().T` ?

Comment: Help me understand. Are you trying to append the sum as a row at the bottom? Or do you want the row of sum to be exported to an excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[10,10,10],
    'B':[10,10,10],
    'C':[10,10,10]
})

df.sum().to_frame().T
```

Result:

```
  A  B  C
0 30 30 30
```

when you do:

```
df.sum()
A    30
B    30
C    30
dtype: int64
```

then you want to make series to df

```
df.sum().to_frame()

0 
A 30
B 30
C 30
```

Comment: Hi kriti thanks for the very quick answer this helps me a lot.. I had one doubt more regarding this..! It would be great if you are available

Comment: Yes I would like to help if I can.